# No Error Log...XAMPP Virtual Host Config?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, xampp, virtualhost

I'm running XAMPP on Windows 7.  `error_log("test")` doesn't output to the my error_log specified in my vhost config (although the access log specified in the same config) does work.

Any ideas?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "c:\Users\User\Example"
  ServerName example.local

  CustomLog "C:\Users\User\Program\logs\local_access.log" combined
  ErrorLog "C:\Users\User\Program\logs\local_error.log"

  <Directory "C:\Users\User\Program">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use XAMPP a lot, but a quick look at the included php.ini file (php/php.ini) shows that `error_log` (the path to the log file, not the function used log an error) is set (to php/logs/php_error.log).

Having this value set would override the default error logging behaviour, and log to the specified file instead of sending the error to mod_php/Apache.

As per [the documentation](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log):

> error_log string
>
> Name of the file where script errors should be logged. The file should
>   be writable by the web server's user. If the special value syslog is
>   used, the errors are sent to the system logger instead. On Unix, this
>   means syslog(3) and on Windows NT it means the event log. The system
>   logger is not supported on Windows 95. See also: syslog(). If this
>   directive is not set, errors are sent to the SAPI error logger. For
>   example, it is an error log in Apache or stderr in CLI.

Comment: This is what it was! Thanks, now I have an error_log I go through :)